# Make fb share button to link to my homepage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, og-meta

I have a og meta on a certain address. 
I wish, however that, when the user clicks on the shared link on their wall, to go to my homepage address (and not to the og page address);

Has anyone accomplish this?